# Facebook Requires extended permission: create_event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this app that create events on behalf of a page. All of a sudden the event creation stopped working, the Graph API giving the following error

```
403 Forbidden: {"error":{"message":"(#290) Requires extended permission: create_event","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

Has there been any recent changes that might have affected my app's functionality? Is there any way to request "create_event" permission as the page? Using for example FB.login() requires me to change back to my user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that due to the Oauth2 change recently (probably), the permission on the old access token was gone (maybe should've thrown something like "invalid access_token" error instead...). Follow the instructions on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ with the create_event permission in addition to manage_pages.